# Why this convert into object

Tags: javascript

Instead of string it is object

```
String.prototype.foo = function () { return this; };
typeof "hello".foo() // object ???
"hello".foo().toString(); //hello
```

it should return string instead i guess.

Comment: tostring converts an object to a string.  Its working as expected.

Comment: Interesting to note that typeof "hello".foo is function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A real string (`"hello"`, `'booya'`) is a primitive value - it doesn't have any functions or anything. It's just a value.

When you do `"string".foo`, it turns into this:

```
Object("string").foo
```

Inside of `foo`, `this` points towards `Object("string")`, not the primitive value. Doing `Object("string")` turns it into an object, so `typeof object === 'object'`.

If you want the "underlying" primitive, call `valueOf`:

```
String.prototype.foo = function () {
    return typeof this.valueOf();
}
"meep".foo(); //string
```

Comment: is it documented somewhere like ECMA specification etc??

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib See [here](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1), the second list. It's interesting to see that it creates an object that's garbage collected, so it doesn't really exist after the call. So: `var string = "string"; string.meep = 4; console.log(string.meep);` logs `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

When you call a method on a string literal (or any other literal for that matter), it is internally converted to a `String` object (or corresponding object). That is what `this` refers to, hence the return value is an object.

The type of any object is `object`, no matter what kind of object it is:

```
typeof new String('foo');
// "object"
```