# using valueOf function in javascript prototype

Tags: javascript

I was reading about javascript prototype and I came accross the following code that extends the Number class to add a function that shows the type of object

```
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
    return typeof (this);
}
(123).toString(); //prints "object"
```

And I read that it is possible to get the primitive representation using the `valueOf` function

```
 n = new Number(123);
 typeof n.valueOf() // prints "number"
```

So I tried to get the premitive representation in the toString function like

```
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
    return typeof (this.valueOf());
}
(123).toString(); //prints "object"
```

I was expecting it to return "number" , but it printed "object" . Is it an expected behaviour or am I missing something in between ?

UPDATE:  Firebug and chrome console prints "object" for me and alert shows number on both cases
UPDATE2 : It was a mistake . console.log ((123).toString()) printed number

Comment: I can't reproduce this - I'm running exactly the code that you have in your last code block (in the Chrome javascript console) and am getting "number" ...

Comment: Same results in IE9 developer tools javascript console (i.e. I get "number" and not "object"). What browser are you using to get "object"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Firebug and chrome console prints "object" for me and alert shows number on both cases

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so you can lose the parenthesis after it. Sry that this observation isn't quite related to your question

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013306/why-this-convert-into-object/8013402#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to make it print anything other than "number". Even if you specifically create an `Object` from a number, it becomes a number.

(I named the method `getType` to avoid any conflicts with the already existing `toString` method. I get the same result using `toString` though.)

```
Number.prototype.getType = function() {
    return typeof this.valueOf();
}
console.log((123).getType()); // prints "number"

var n = 123;
console.log(n.getType()); // prints "number"

var o = new Number(123);
console.log(o.getType()); // prints "number"

var x = new Object(123);
console.log(x.getType()); // prints "number"
```

I have tested this in IE (10, 9, 8, 7), Firefox and Chrome, and get the same result.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Xc7TC/

Comment: Thank you. It was a mistake. I was missing console.log

Answer (score 1):

When calling a method on a *primitive* such as `42` JavaScript automatically converts it to its corresponding object. The same happens (at least in IE) when you use a primitive as `this` via `.call()` or `.apply()`.

The explanation for this behaviour can be found in the [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1):

> The following [[Get]] internal method is used by GetValue when V is a property reference with a primitive base value. It is called using base as its this value and with property P as its argument. The following steps are taken:
>
> Let O be `ToObject(base)`.

It does not happen in [*strict mode*](http://es5.github.com/#C) by the way:

> If this is evaluated within strict mode code, then the this value is not coerced to an object.

---

The reason why `valueOf()` does not return the primitive [is here](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.4.4):

> Returns [this Number value](http://es5.github.com/#this-Number-value).

following that reference:

> the phrase “this Number value” refers to either the Number value represented by this Number object, that is, the value of the [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of this Number object **or the this value if its type is Number**.

Comment: Yes but I thought this.valueOf() will return a primitive  but it returns an object

Answer (score 1):

It can be broken down to this:

```
// Case 1
typeof (Number(123));        // "number"

// Case 2
typeof (new Number(123));     // "object"
```

Question is why?

*Case 1:* This is because `Number(123)` is really a function call that converts its argument value `123` into a value of type `Number`.

*Case 2:* `new Number(123)` creates a `Number` *object* using the argument value, this is directly calling `Number` *constructor* because of the `new`; hence we get type `object` at the end.